# Adding a new relationship breaks calculation

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop, data-modeling

A software company is selling its product to all major car manufacturer.

The software is divided into:

- **multi-tenant resources:** resources that are shared between customers (which are car manufacturer like Mercedes, AUDI, BMW, Volkswagen, etc...)
- **single-tenant resources:** resources that are dedicated to a single customer (in the example BMW)

so my goal is to calculate how much BMW is costing for both multi-tenant and single-tenant resources.

I created a mock up that you can download here:

- [.pbix](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArldK_gE2gPUldFiB925DrRlH51gjw?e=Fx7ahD)
- [.xlsx](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArldK_gE2gPUldFjSLfiiTDKkz0lSA?e=RNNzMl)

As you can see I can calculate the multi-tenant resources but not the single-tenant resources :

[image]

As soon as I create a relationship that could help me calculate the single-tenant resources I succeeded!

...but now the multi-tenant resources are broken.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Why one relationship is deleting the other one?

Or make the other glitch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I can only tell you the reason but not the fix as I don't understand your data model and data domain. You need to create a proper star schema for PBI to work. The reason you are seeing what you're seeing is that you're creating an ambiguous model. The data model is everything in PBI and the relationships dictate how filters are propagated from table to table.

Before you create your new relationship, Sample Data is being filtered by SSRS which in turn is being filtered by Tenant which in turn is filtered by Client. By introducing a relationship directly between Client and Sample Data, you have created a more direct relationship for filters to propagate and PBI is using the shortest path.

Ideally, you need a fact table and dimension tables. You should also write DAX for your measures so you can control calculations with things like USERELATIONSHIP().

Data modelling is quite difficult in PBI and is usually where most people come unstuck.

Comment: It's what I suspected. As you can see I did the star schema for Tenant (fact table) with SSRS, Database, Sector9 and Client (dimension table) orbiting around. 
But then the star collides into what I would call "wall schema": a NoSQL blob of data untangled between them. Sample Data is in fact the bill of all the costs and there is no relation. 
I will search on internet how to link two separate star schema or something like that. 
Thank you again for saving my ass.

Answer (score 1):

Davide Bacci is right, the true solution is to create a better diagram.

However I found a [patch](https://exceleratorbi.com.au/multiple-relationships-between-tables-in-dax/#comment-158506) for now by using `USERELATIONSHIP`.

Because one calculation was working but the other not I just drag and drop the relationships like I showed in the GIF **but I deactivated it**.

Then I used the DAX formula:

```
Cost_by_ResourceGroup = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Sample Data'[costInBillingCurrency]),
    USERELATIONSHIP(Client[ClientCode], 'Sample Data'[tags])
)
```

As result the first calculation works because of the relationship. The second because of the `USERELATIONSHIP`.

> WARNING:

This means bypassing the problem. Not solving the problem.

I'm still kicking the can down the road till I don't face this problem again. But one day or another I need to take care of the ER diagram.