# Power BI :: should I use USERELATIONSHIP, CROSSFILTER, TREATAS or JOIN?

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop, data-modeling

I have a simple model which relationship can be represented like this:

[image]

The blue line relationship is disabled and the two tables that I currently want to represent they look like this:

[image]

If I enable the missing relationship between **Sample Data** and **Client** the contrary happens!

Now the second box works but the first box shows weird data:

[image]

Because I have previously used [USERELATIONSHIP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77130680/adding-a-new-relationship-breaks-calculation) to bypass such problem I tried to do the same hare for the calculation of that column in the first table:

```
Cost_SSRS_test = CALCULATE(SUM('Sample Data'[costInBillingCurrency]),
USERELATIONSHIP(SSRS[SSRS Resource Group],'Sample Data'[resourceGroupName]))
```

And this time I do the contrary: I **disable** the relationship between **SSRS** and **Sample Data**: something strange happens:

[image]

Both columns are wrong but the first just repeats `2,179.40` on every line.
The second represents different values.

I want to understand USERELATIONSHIP because in my last question I have used it without really understanding what that meant.

I see that there are different commands like `FILTER`, `CROSSFILTER`, `TREATAS`, `CROSSJOIN`, `NATURALJOIN`, etc... but I don't know what to use to calculate that value based on that **disabled relationships** that actually works.

I really want to understand how to link these two tables and this will be the occasion for me to learn.

You can download the files here:

- [.pbix](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArldK_gE2gPUldFiB925DrRlH51gjw?e=04mXiy)
- [.xlsx](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArldK_gE2gPUldFjSLfiiTDKkz0lSA?e=LiS2nD)

Thank you.

Comment: Take a step backwards. What are you trying to accomplish? Forget all about PowerBI and answer that one first. You need USERELATIONSHIP() if you need to use an inactive relationship between two tables... like if you're using the AdventureWorksDW dataset and you want to summarize Sales by ShipDate instead of the default OrderDate relationship.

Comment: @Pieter in my example BMW has multi-tenant resources shared with other customers and single-tenant resources dedicated to BMW (like a database). 
As I link the customer code with the tag I can indeed find all single-tenant resources as they have a 1:1 relationship. But the multi-tenant resources that are shared between BMW, Mercedes, AUDI, etc.. they are now broken because the same resource is dedicated to 3-4 or more customers. 
Let me know if that is clear for you.

Comment: USERELATIONSHIP() is dead simple. It's used inside CALCULATE() to "activate"/use an otherwise inactive relationship between two tables. In SQL-speak, it lets you change the join criteria (join columns) between two tables.

Any chance you could post a tiny bit of sample data? (Don't need the whole thing, just a representative slice)

Comment: The sample data are inside the post. At the end you can find a link to the pbix and the xlsx

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Recovering from kidney stones. I will be back in 2 days and I will net you know. Knowing you it will probably work. Next week I will post a SQL Script that can create the database and will show you the diagram: I think it's already a star diagram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a proper star schema with a fact table and dimension tables so it will always be an uphill battle against the engine. You also have what is known as an ambiguous model. Even where you say the first screenshot is OK, if you look at the total, it is not correct.

[image]

It is very difficult to advise when we don't understand your data domain but regardless, you can force the engine to do what you want. Enable the inactive relationship as it looks correct to me. For the measure in the top table, add the following:

```
Measure = CALCULATE(SUM('Sample Data'[costInBillingCurrency]), CROSSFILTER(Client[ClientCode], 'Sample Data'[tags], None), CROSSFILTER(Tenant[SSRSConfigID], SSRS[ID],Both))
```

This forces the disablement of one relationship and ensures bi-direction for another so the filter can travel from table to table.

[image]

Data modelling is difficult in Power BI and all I can suggest is that you read up. SQLBI videos like the following are excellent as are other deep dives by Alberto: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x3m7qzsVJqQ

I highly recommend all the content from SQLBI - you can learn so much from their articles and youtube videos and they do paid courses too if you prefer to learn that way.

Comment: It worked. The trick was to use `CROSSFILTER None` and `CROSSFILTER Both`. I saw Alberto's video but without your help I couldn't have applied to my case. 
I'm going to publish a new post where I will script my database diagram: I think it's already a star schema.

Comment: Great stuff. As I said, modelling is tricky and I encounter issues all the time in trying to get a "perfect" model. Theory and reality never quite line up.

Comment: Hi @David, this is my question about the Star Schema: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77216154/power-bi-is-this-a-valid-star-schema . I'm quite sure that this is a star schema but I will accept any feedback

Answer (score 0):

oh, I get it now. Sorry. I'm slow. 
Basically, if you have some resources that are single-tenant, and some that are multi-tenant, you just model them all as multi-tenant, and single-tenant ones just have a single record in the junction table. (This is where some database background helps).

Customer---(1)---USES---(M)---Resource   (Single-tenant)

Customer--(M)--USES---(M)---Resource (Multi-tenant)

in the first instance (1:M), The "owner"/"UserID" of the resource gets saved in the resource table. (because a resource is owned by exactly one tenant.) In the second, "Owns" becomes a table consisting of at least (CustomerKey, ResourceKey), and then whatever columns describe the customerKey AND ResourceKey (the relationship). So in your model, *all* of the "Uses"/tenancy records would go into the junction table. You'd know it was a single-tenancy if there was only one CustomerKey in the "uses" table per ResourceKey.

What you are modeling is a Many-to-many relationship:
One Customer can use one or more Resources, AND
Each Resource can be used by (shared) more than one Customer.

The part you have to remember is that when you're modeling, you have to model for what is *always* true, and although the "one to many" relationship between Customers and Resources is usually "one to many", it is not always the case. So your only option is to model it as many to many (junction table).

Comment: No, using M:M relationships is not an option as it generates wrong totals. I have already divided multi-tenant (SSRS) and single-tenant (Client). 
Download the file and try to find a solution. I'm awarding 300 points as a bounty because this reply is not easy