# Ambiguity Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, ambiguity

I need to use inside a measure the city names of the Customers and the Stores (both looking up into Geography Table). When I try to connect Customer Table with Sales Table there is an obvious problem of ambiguity.

What is the best way to solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: whats the exact problem? in my understanting, the relationship that you are showing looks correct...one customer can by X times.

Comment: The answer is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77159040/power-bi-should-i-use-userelationship-crossfilter-treatas-or-join

Comment: The problem is that when trying to activate the relationship I get the following message: "You can´t create a direct active relationhsip between Sales and Customers because that would introduce ambiguity between tables Geography and Sales. " Which I think I understand because there are 2 different "routes " to filter Sales from Geography.