# Power BI :: Is this a valid star schema?

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop, data-modeling

I've been helped by Davide Bacci in [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77159040/power-bi-should-i-use-userelationship-crossfilter-treatas-or-join) and I thank him so much.

However one question was raised: is my schema a valid star schema? I think so:

[image]

I have also a backup of the database with anonymized data that you can download here:

- [.bak](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArldK_gE2gPUldQQCxvRXJ5vpmuhYw?e=CQfHTZ)
- [.pbix](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArldK_gE2gPUldQPMrXJmAPkgtHClQ?e=BnUsDb)

And if you import it into Power BI the model couldn't be more starry:

[image]

So I don't see where the problem is.

This schema is a star schema to me.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: In a proper start schema, there are no 1:1 or M:M relations - only 1:M. So, your "Database" - "Tenant" structure needs redesign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the surface, it looks like a star schema with a central fact table and surrounding dimensions linked by uni-directional one-to-many relationships so seems fine to me. My limited feedback:

1. Database to Tenant is 1-2-1. There is nothing wrong with this for logical separation of entities but sometimes 1-2-1 relationships are just merged into the same table to simplify the model. No big deal either way.
2. Your central fact table has a suspiciously large number of columns. Usually, fact tables are long and thin and dimension table are short and wide. Do you need all those columns in your fact table as usually the only things in there are figures to aggregate and foreign keys to dimensions. For instance, what are the following?

[image]

You already have a dimension table for Tenant so do these not belong in that table?

3. Your keys are all GUIDs. Some people say it is best practice to replace these with a simple index in PQ but it isn't a big deal as they effectively get replaced by dictionary encoding anyway.
4. Remove any columns not used in your report. It just makes things more efficient and easier to parse.
5. Hide the columns on the many side (fact table) so you are always forced to use the dimension.
6. Set a key column on your fact table:

[image]

Much better than the model in the other question which was basically an ambiguous circle.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Davide. The problem is that now I need to link this star schema with that Sample Data and I will create the ambiguous circle again. 
And I cannot avoid that because while one is a star schema the Sample Data is a NoSQL database without any relation: these are the raw data coming from Azure bill where a raw is created every few seconds for a whole month.

Comment: So maybe I asked the wrong question. The question is: how can I link a star schema to a NoSQL database without any relation? This is the problem

Comment: Not sure I understand. Best post a new question with details.